# $.ajax is not working in Firefox and Safari || Error MSG : NetworkError: A network error occurred

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, safari

$.ajax is not working / not posting in Firefox and Safari. I'm getting an error Message in Firefox "NetworkError: A network error occurred."

I tried keeping `async:false` but the data is not updating in to MySQL.

It is a cross-browser data

jQuery version is 1.12.4

```
    $.ajax({

     url: 'http://xyz.in/test/sign2.php',
     dataType: 'text',
     cache: false,
     processData: false,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: form_data,
     type: 'post',
     success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);

                            }
       });
```

---

Comment: Is it a cross domain request? Is it working on other browsers

Comment: Thanks for the Comment. Yes It is a cross domain and it is working on Chrome and IE.

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed on Firefox/Safari? Do you see anything else in the browser console? Also try to clear the browser cache and retest again

Comment: No Luck! Same Issue